# How to get the category name from list.phtml in Magento

Tags: php, magento

So i am trying to display a custom list.phtml file from within a block. 
thats fine i am able to display all the products with category id 6.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="6" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

the above works fine. But now i want to get access to category id 6's name, how would i go about doing this from within list.phtml or even from within a different block. i just need the name of the category for the id =6 .

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Inside the list.phtml block template you can get the category name with

```
<?php echo $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getName() ?>
```

In this case the current category is set on the layer by the `catalog/product_list` block in the `_getProductCollection()` call.

Inside the CMS page content there is no way I know of to access the category name directly.
From a different block getting the category name might be more involved. You can try

```
<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getName() ?>
```

Of course it might be the case that there is no current category might set on the layer instance, so make sure to check for that to avoid ugly errors.
Basically, if the `catalog/product_list` product list block's `_beforeToHtml()` method has been executed the current category will be set on the layer.

**EDIT:**
All this is assuming you want to get the category name without specifying the category ID again. If you don't care about that you can always get the category name with

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId())->getName() ?>
```

Comment: both of these break the page and nothing is outputted, how do i set the current layer?

Comment: this is the error Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in magento

Comment: The current layer in the registry is set by the catalog search module. I updated the answer to use `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')` instead, and also added an explanation when the current category is set on the layer instance.

Comment: `<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getName() ?>
`this actually gives me the top level category name. its id is 2. i think this is a little strange. category 6 is inside catergory 2. also i need it to be dynamic because i will call `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="xx" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
` multiple times on this cms page. i need the category name for each call i make to this block depending on the id.

Comment: Try setting the `type="catalog/navigation"` instead. Then use `$this->getStoreCategories()` and run a `foreach` loop on the store categories, comparing each category id to `$this->getData('category_id')`. If you want it to be even more dynamic, you can also use `$this->getCurrentChildCategories()`, but on the home page, that will return the same list as `$this->getStoreCategories()` because the current `layer` will be equal to your store's root category (id: 2 from what it sounds like).

Comment: `<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId())->getName() ?>` should definitely work.

Comment: <?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getData('category_id'))->getName() ?>